# How to detect the number of days that a person passed in a city?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I have the following mapping in Elasticsearch:

```
PUT /traffic-data
{
    "mappings": {
      "traffic-entry": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
        "properties": {
          "CameraId": {
            "type":"keyword"
          },
          "VehiclePlateNumber": {
            "type":"keyword"
          },
          "DateTime": {
            "type":"date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I want to calculate how many days per month has a vehicle stayed. A unique vehicle is identified by `VehiclePlateNumber`.
So, I want to get the result something like this:

```
VehiclePlaneNumber   Month   StayDays
111                  1       5
222                  1       1
...
```

How can I do it using Elasticsearch query?

This is what I tried:

```
GET traffic-data/_search?
{
"size": 0, 
  "aggs":{
    "by_district":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "VehiclePlateNumber",
        "size": 100000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_month": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "DateTime",
            "size": 12
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please paste sample data for 111, 222 VehiclePlaneNumber to analyze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do terms aggregation on Vehicle plate number then a terms sub agg on month then a sum sub agg on days.

Something like:

```
GET traffic-data/_search
{
"size": 0, 
  "aggs":{
    "by_district":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "VehiclePlateNumber",
        "size": 100000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_month": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "DateTime",
            "size": 12
          },
          "aggs": {
            "days": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "days"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Month should be a scripted field but would be better to compute it at index time.

That should work.

Or you can use entity centric design and regularly index that value computed. See https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/2015/sf/building-entity-centric-indexes

Comment: Well, indeed I have also sfield `Month` and `Monthday` that are extracted from `DateTime`. Could you please show how to sum sub aggs on days?